# WSO2 developer studio making car file faulty on deployment

Tags: apache, maven, wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 Developer studio 3.7.0 to deploy my ESB project on to the carbon server. But every time i deploy it WSO2 ESB makes my CAR file **faulty**. On the developer studio side there is no error. It shows build successful and deployment successful too.

**Note:**

I am using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 and WSO2 developer studio 3.7.0. I am using apache maven.

**My CAR project "pom.xml".**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.Template_CAR</groupId>
  <artifactId>Template_CAR</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>carbon/application</packaging>
  <name>Template_CAR</name>
  <description>Template_CAR</description>
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>local</id>
      <url>file:/home/omerkhalid/Documents/</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
  <properties>
    <maven.car.deploy.skip>false</maven.car.deploy.skip>
    <com.example.Template_ESB.template_._HelloWorldLogger>capp/EnterpriseServiceBus</com.example.Template_ESB.template_._HelloWorldLogger>
    <com.example.Template_ESB.proxy-service_._TemplateService>capp/EnterpriseServiceBus</com.example.Template_ESB.proxy-service_._TemplateService>
    <artifact.types>jaggery/app=zip,service/rule=aar,lib/library/bundle=jar,synapse/message-processors=xml,synapse/endpointTemplate=xml,synapse/proxy-service=xml,synapse/message-store=xml,carbon/application=car,registry/resource=zip,lib/dataservice/validator=jar,synapse/endpoint=xml,web/application=war,synapse/sequence=xml,synapse/configuration=xml,lib/registry/handlers=jar,synapse/task=xml,service/meta=xml,webapp/jaxws=war,synapse/api=xml,cep/bucket=xml,bpel/workflow=zip,lib/registry/filter=jar,service/dataservice=dbs,synapse/local-entry=xml,synapse/priority-executor=xml,synapse/event-source=xml,synapse/template=xml,lib/carbon/ui=jar,service/axis2=aar,synapse/sequenceTemplate=xml,wso2/gadget=dar,lib/synapse/mediator=jar</artifact.types>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example.Template_ESB.proxy-service</groupId>
      <artifactId>TemplateService</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <type>xml</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example.Template_ESB.template</groupId>
      <artifactId>HelloWorldLogger</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <type>xml</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <id>wso2-nexus</id>
      <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>wso2-maven2-repository-1</id>
      <url>http://dist.wso2.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>wso2-nexus-repository-1</id>
      <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <id>wso2-nexus</id>
      <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>wso2-maven2-repository-1</id>
      <url>http://dist.wso2.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>wso2-nexus-repository-1</id>
      <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <buildcommands />
          <projectnatures>
            <projectnature>org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.distribution.project.nature</projectnature>
          </projectnatures>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.wso2.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-car-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>car</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>car</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration />
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.wso2.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-car-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.9</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <carbonServers>
            <CarbonServer>
              <trustStorePath>/home/omerkhalid/Documents/WSO2/wso2esb-4.8.1/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</trustStorePath>
              <trustStorePassword>wso2carbon</trustStorePassword>
              <trustStoreType>JKS</trustStoreType>
              <serverUrl>https://localhost:9443</serverUrl>
              <userName>admin</userName>
              <password>admin</password>
              <operation>deploy</operation>
            </CarbonServer>
          </carbonServers>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**Exception on WSO2 ESB Management Console**
[image: WSO2 ESB Run Time Management Console]

**Fault Reason:**

```
 org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: ProxyService Deployment from the file : /home/omerkhalid/Documents/WSO2/wso2esb-4.8.1/repository/carbonapps/work/1422113107556Template_CAR_1.0.0.car/TemplateService_1.0.0/TemplateService-1.0.0.xml : Failed. at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:211) at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifacts(SynapseAppDeployer.java:100) at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager.deployCarbonApp(ApplicationManager.java:251) at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.CappAxis2Deployer.deploy(CappAxis2Deployer.java:114) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67) at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:79) at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:124) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: ProxyService Deployment from the file : /home/omerkhalid/Documents/WSO2/wso2esb-4.8.1/repository/carbonapps/work/1422113107556Template_CAR_1.0.0.car/TemplateService_1.0.0/TemplateService-1.0.0.xml : Failed. at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:199) ... 20 more Caused by: org.apache.synapse.deployers.SynapseArtifactDeploymentException: ProxyService Deployment from the file : /home/omerkhalid/Documents/WSO2/wso2esb-4.8.1/repository/carbonapps/work/1422113107556Template_CAR_1.0.0.car/TemplateService_1.0.0/TemplateService-1.0.0.xml : Failed. at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.handleSynapseArtifactDeploymentError(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:473) at org.apache.synapse.deployers.ProxyServiceDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(ProxyServiceDeployer.java:97) at org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.ProxyServiceDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(ProxyServiceDeployer.java:46) at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:192) ... 20 more Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658) at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.ValueFactory.isDynamicKey(ValueFactory.java:124) at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.ValueFactory.createValue(ValueFactory.java:59) at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.InvokeMediatorFactory.buildParameters(InvokeMediatorFactory.java:77) at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.InvokeMediatorFactory.createSpecificMediator(InvokeMediatorFactory.java:62) at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AbstractMediatorFactory.createMediator(AbstractMediatorFactory.java:91) at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MediatorFactoryFinder.getMediator(MediatorFactoryFinder.java:223) at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AbstractListMediatorFactory.addChildren(AbstractListMediatorFactory.java:41) at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.SequenceMediatorFactory.createAnonymousSequence(SequenceMediatorFactory.java:70) at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.ProxyServiceFactory.createProxy(ProxyServiceFactory.java:178) at org.apache.synapse.deployers.ProxyServiceDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(ProxyServiceDeployer.java:56) ... 22 more
```

Comment: Is it possible to add content of TemplateService-1.0.0.xml ( source view) and artifact.xml files of the synapse-project and car project file. By looking at the exception, What I think is, TemplateService is referring to a resource which is not included in the car file. I may be wrong. Source view may help to understand exact problem.

Comment: I was creating the CAR project from developer studio dashboard but when i made it from File->New->CompositeApplicationProject. it started working. I did not change a single thing in my esb project. This is the most strangest behaviour i have ever seen from WSO2 developer studio.